How to write requests based on many to many relationships in graphql?
I'm following the firebase tutorial on dataconnect, which gives us the following graphql schema:
type User @table(key: "uid") {
    uid: String!
    name: String!
    address: String!
}

type Email @table {
    subject: String!
    sent: Date!
    text: String!
    from: User!
}

type Recipient @table(key: ["email", "user"]) {
    email: Email!
    user: User!
}

I am now wondering how to perform more subtle requests than just filtering lists. For example, how would I list the couple of users who have sent mails to each other? Or even better, those who have never corresponded?
I started with that :
#list couples who have written to each other
query ListMatched @auth(level: PUBLIC){
    couples: recipients{
        sender : email {
            from { name }
        }
        receiver : user{name}
    }
}

But I don't know how to go from there. It seems like I can't use a distinct keyword?
